# Qt child widget does not paint on empty canvas

Tags: c++, qt

I have a parent QGLWidget which has a child QWidget with only a QSlider. The initialisation of the child widget happens in the constructor of the parents:

```
GLWidget::GLWidget(const QGLFormat& format, TimeControllers time_controllers,
                ViewControllers view_controllers, TerrainControllers terrain_controllers, TemperatureEditDialog * temp_edit_dlg,
                Actions * render_actions, Actions* overlay_actions, Actions * control_actions, Actions * show_actions,
                QWidget * parent) :  m_latitude_controller(this) {
...
```

Where **m_latitude_controller** is the QWidget in question.

On first load, it looks fine:
[image: on first load]

However, if I use the slider, it turns into this:

[image: on slider use]

Long story short, it seems that on repaint events, the QWidget is not redrawing from scratch but rather drawing over what is previously there. Any ideas?

Comment: Plain QWidgets over QGLWidgets were never properly supported. Can you move to Qt 5 and QOpenGLWidget?

Comment: It'd be useful to know your version of Qt. On Qt 5.4 and up, you should be using `QOpenGLWidget` and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @peppe. It was indeed because I was using Qt < 5. I updated to Qt 5.4 and the overlaying widget now works. If you post this as an answer I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was down to the version of Qt I was using. I ported to Qt 5.4 and used QOpenGlWidget rather than QGLWidget and it works.